# Retrieving table data from a doc file using c#

Tags: c#, interop

I am working on a project which involves getting data from a .doc or a .docx file. The input requirements are in a tabular format. Is it possible to retrieve data from table in a row wise manner or as a dataset.I am using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word** to get the data from the doc file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the property Tables of the Document interface to get a collection with all the tables in your document. For each Table in this collection you can get the rows and for each row the cells.

I.e. if app is your Application object you can write something like this to get the text contained in each cell(supposing that there is exactly one in your doc):

```
    string aCellText;
    foreach (Row aRow in Application.ActiveDocument.Tables[0].Rows)
        foreach (Cell aCell in aRow.Cells)
            aCellText = aCell.Range.Text;
```

Comment: It works. thanks, People are talking about doing in excel,which is easy,I need this as i have to retrieve details form a large doc requirement.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible with the word, but if you want something like that than you should put tabular data in you excel file and than you can easily read it in the dataset object....

Comment: oh..:( It is possible to add tables to a document , so i thought the reverse would be possible..

Comment: It is possible. It isn't something that I would do, but it's possible anyway.

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli - yes with the help of execl its possible you can google out and find number of example of it

Comment: No, I mean in Word without using Excel, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible to get the data in dataset object from .doc or .docx file. But if your data is in tabular form and also in the excel sheet than you can retrieve the data in dataset object. MS Word is for documentation purpose and excel is used for maintaining data sheets..

Comment: " MS Word is for documentation purpose and excel is used for maintaining data sheets". I know this. I am, asking is there any way to recognize a table which is present in a doc file. FYI lists,para etc can be recognized separately.